# Troubles with reference variables/pointers an class members [C++]

Tags: c++, class, reference

I've been working on a project and have quite a few classes, a few of which look like this:

```
class A
{
    // stuff;
};

class B
{
    A& test;

public:
    B(A& _test) :
        test(_test)
    {};
    void doStuff();
};

class C
{
    A foo;
    B bar(foo);

    void exp()
    {
        bar.doStuff();
    }
};
```

This ends up breaking in class C when C::foo is not a type name. In my bigger project, where everything is broken up into their separate .cpp and .h files, I don't see that error if I #include"C.h" in B.h, but there is still an error in C.cpp where bar is completely unrecognized by my compiler (Visual Studio 2013). There error persists even if A& is an A* instead (changing the code from references to pointers where necessary, of course). Does anyone have any tips to what is going on here?

Comment: What does "breaking" mean?  Compiler error?  Runtime error?  Unexpected results?

Comment: B bar(foo) has compiler error ( member "C::foo" is not a type name) which ends up breaking the project with compiler errors

Comment: side note: you are passing a temporary copy to the reference, your `B(A _test)` should be `B(A& _test)`.

Comment: Yeah, that was a type from getting a quick type up for an example. My main concern is where C:foo is not a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code:

```
B bar(foo);
```

Attempts to declare a member function named `bar` which returns a `B` and takes an argument of type `foo`. However, in your code, `foo` is not a type - it's a variable. I'm guessing you meant to initialize `bar` instead:

```
B bar{foo}; // non-static data member initializers must be done with {}S
```

or just write out the constructor:

```
C()
: bar(foo)
{ }
```

Additionally, this constructor assigns your reference `test` to the temporary `_test`:

```
B(A _test) :
    test(_test)
{ }
```

You want to take `_test` by reference:

```
B(A& _test) : test(_test) { }
```

Comment: Ah! That works. I'm so used to using the constructor when the object is created, thanks.

edit: and like I said above, that test being reference was just a type from getting a quick example typed up